# how to control gap of 2 inline figures in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

in one cell, I'd like to output 2 plotly figures one by the other one, how to control the gap of these 2 inline figures? I'd like them to be very close with small gap.

```
import plotly as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
py.offline.iplot(fi1)
py.offline.iplot(fig2)
```